# Shift/Reduce Conflict in Yacc/Flex

Tags: c, yacc, flex-lexer, lr-grammar

I have this grammar in yacc:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%token texto SEP ERRO word

%start Ini

%%

Ini: Directivas SEP SEP Conceitos '$'
            { printf("Terminou bem...\n"); return 0; };

Directivas: Directiva
          | Directivas SEP Directiva
          ;

Conceitos: Conceito
         | Conceitos SEP SEP Conceito
         ;

Conceito: word SEP Atributos;

Atributos: Atributo
         | Atributos SEP Atributo
         ;

Directiva: texto;
Atributo: '-' texto;

%%

int main(){
    yyparse();
}

int yyerror(char *s){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
```

And in flex:

```
%{
    #include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

[a-zA-Z]+           return word;

[a-zA-Z ]+          return texto;

\-                  return '-';

\n                  return SEP;

[ \t]               ;

.                   return ERRO;

<<EOF>>             return '$';
```

I want to make a parse that valids something like:

```
text line
text line
text line

word
-text line
-text line
-text line

word
-text line
```

where the first lines are the 'Directivas' and then one blank line and then it comes the 'Conceitos' where one Conceito is one word followed by a few text lines with a '-' in the begin. those 'Conceitos are separated by one blank line

but it finds a shift/reduce conflitct.. i am new in this and i cant find out why

Sorry for my english

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use yacc's (or bison's) `-v` option to get a full listing of the generated parser and the grammar conflicts in the `y.output` file.  When you do this with your grammar, you get something like (from bison):

```
State 16 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
        :
state 16

    6 Conceito: word SEP Atributos .
    8 Atributos: Atributos . SEP Atributo

    SEP  shift, and go to state 20

    SEP       [reduce using rule 6 (Conceito)]
    $default  reduce using rule 6 (Conceito)
```

This tells you exactly where the conflict is -- after reducing an `Attributos` and looking at a `SEP` lookahead, the parser doesn't know if it should shift the `SEP` to parse another `Atributo` after it, or to reduce the `Conceito`, which would only be valid if there's another `SEP` after the `SEP` (two token lookahead needed).

One way to avoid this would be to have your lexer return multiple `SEP`s (blank lines) as a single token:

```
\n      return SEP;
\n\n    return SEP_SEP;
```

You might want to allow whitespace on the blank line or more than a single blank line instead:

```
\n([ \t]*\n)+  return SEP_SEP;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the tip about -v is really helping me!!

Comment: @chris-dodd: what can I do if the `-v` option does not change the output, and right now it's just giving me the number of shift/reduce conflicts?

Comment: @distilledchaos: The `-v` option creates an additional output file (with a `.output` extension) with the detailed information.